# Why does sh:NodeShape not have sh:name and sh:description properties?

Tags: shacl

When reading the [SHACL](https://www.w3.org/TR/shacl/#name) specification I noticed we can add a `sh:name` and `sh:description` to a `sh:PropertyShape` which is meant to

> provide human-readable labels for the property in the target where it appears

which is really cool for properties but I am a bit confused why this is not the case for `sh:NodeShape` too. Would it not be helpful to provide human-readable names and descriptions for 'types' too?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For node shapes, simply use rdfs:label and rdfs:comment. These properties already exist and are used for similar annotation purposes, e.g. for classes.

We needed to mint new properties for property shapes because rdfs:label and rdfs:comment would be about the sh:PropertyShape itself while sh:name and sh:description are about the sh:path of the property shape.

Comment: Great, I never read the specification in such a way that sh:name is about sh:path and not about sh:PropertyShape.